# Get next element of specific tag type in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm iterating through a list of elements using jsoup, but periodically need to find one element that doesn't occur directly after the current element.

For example, if I'm iterating through and come to an `img` tag, I want to find the very next `a` tag occurring after that `img` tag. But, there could be a few tags in between the two.

Here's some example code:

```
for (Element e : elements) {
    if (e.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {
        // Do some stuff with "img" tag
        // Now, find the next tag in the list with tag <a>
    }

    // Do some other things before the next loop iteration
}
```

I thought something like `e.select("img ~ a")` should work, but it returns no results.

What's a good way of doing this in jsoup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be *a* way of accomplishing the stated goal. Not sure it's the most efficient, but it is the most straightforward.

```
Element node = e.nextElementSibling();
while (node != null && !node.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
    node = node.nextElementSibling();
}
```

I was hoping for a way to run the equivalent of `e.nextElementSibling("a")`. Perhaps something  for me to contribute back to jsoup ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the nextElementSibling() method.

Inside your if statement add the following code:

```
Element imgNext = e.nextElementSibling();
do {
    Element a = imgNext.select("a[href]").first();         
} while (imgNext!=null && a==null);
```

Comment: This is actually an infinite loop. If "a" isn't found to be something other than `null` the first time through, then the loop will never end.